# **Cannot** using the following code via selenium to click <i class="E"></i> with href="#"

Tags: python, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Cannot** using the following code via selenium to click

`<a href="#" class="C" rel="D" style="display: block;"><i class="E"></i></a>` no hyperlink in href tag `<a href="#"></a>` no text `<i class="E"></i>` so that **cannot be click**

*i save the HTML code into **tmpfile.org**, it just last an hours, so the URL may be expired

**Python Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver.get("https://tmpfiles.org/dl/65768/button_2021.html")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//href[@class="E"]//a").click()
```

**HTML code**

```
html = """<html><body><div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <a href="#" class="C" rel="D" style="display: block;">
      <i class="E"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
<div class="B">
<span class="J" id="I">H</span>
  </div>
  <div class="B">
    <a href="#" class="F" rel="" style="display: none;">
  <i class="G"></i>
</a>
</div>
&nbsp;
<div id="B" class="B"><div>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="pno">K</a>
</div> <div>
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="pno">L</a>
</div> <div>
</div></body></html>"""
```

Comment: Are you getting any error if you use the xpath you provided?

Comment: dear, error message attached, thanks !

Comment: Mary, you need to understand that if you can click something manually then that process can be automated, if you can not click manually, it's an functional issue and should be reported to web application developer.

Comment: dear, i can click the URL when using browser

Comment: I can see H, K, and L. which one you are clicking ?

Comment: dear, i want to click  " [''] " which is refer to <i class="E"></i>

Comment: i guess the website will run the script

Comment: i tried  driver.find_elements_by_class_name('B')[0] but not success

Comment: when you say you want to click on ` i want to click " [''] " ` , where is this on UI ?

Comment: dear, it will click the script, i guess, anyway, i solved, thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first list out all elements with following code:

```
a = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('B')
c = []
for x in a:
    c.append(x.text)
print(c)
```

and we can see some result in the elements, which mean we may do sth on it

**Execution Result**

```
['']
['', 'H']
['', 'H', '']
['', 'H', '', 'K\nL']
```

and then using the following code to click

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('B')[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

two things :

```
find_elements
```

returns a list so you can not use `click` on it. since `click` is just for `single web element.`

this xpath `//href[@class="E"]//a` is wrong since href is not a tag.

Instead do this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='E']/..").click()
```

but it should not redirect you anywhere since **href** has `#` which will not redirect you nowhere.

**Update 1 :**

In case you want to click on `'K'`, you can use below code :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "K"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: What do you wanna do on the page ? Do you want to click on `K` or `L` ?

Comment: in case you are interested to click on `K`, you can use the updated code above

Comment: dear, it seem not work, anyway, thanks !  want to click <i class="E"></i>

Comment: You can not click on `//i[@class='E']` this, cause it does not have any `href` to redirect to. Tell me in the UI, which element you want to click is it H or K or L ? further `H` is not clickable you can check manually as well. and in case if you want to click on `K`, I have given you code above under update 1 section.

Answer (score 1):

See if this works, I assume you are trying to click on `a` tag above `<i class='E'>`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='E']//ancestor::a[@class='C']").click()
```

Comment: dear, it seem not work, anyway, thanks !  i want to click <i class="E"></i>